# MomentJS and JS Date objects not referring to the same hour

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I've got a server instance (NodeJS) that receives a set of objects, and schedules them for sending push notifications to users.

Some of these objects, are periodic, and this periodicity is handled by a string like this:

```
90=>Mon&Tue&Thu=>16:00
```

Which is read as:

```
offset_minutes=>days_of_the_week=>initial_hour
```

Then, what I do is to check whether the current day matches one of the given days in the string, and then, modify the date to the given hour in the "initial_hour", and finally, substract the "offset_minutes" amount of minutes from the Date object.

Seems straightforward until now, right? Well, not that much. Let's first see the code:

```
const isToday = weekDays.split("&")
            .map(a => {
                switch (a) {
                    case 'Mon': return 1;
                    case 'Tue': return 2;
                    case 'Wed': return 3;
                    case 'Thu': return 4;
                    case 'Fri': return 5;
                    case 'Sat': return 6;
                    case 'Sun': return 7;
                }
            })
            .some(v => v == currentDay);

        if (isToday) {

            let finalDate = moment(today)
                .set("hour", Number(hour))
                .set("minute", Number(mins));


            if (offset) {
             finalDate.subtract('minutes', Number(offset));
            }


            return finalDate.toDate();
```

Everything works well, until I do the MomentJS transformations. When I output a Date object with the ".toDate()" method, this object **is always set to 2 hours before the expected time**. But if I use the .toISOString() method, I get the proper time for all the occurrencies.

I guess that something is wrong with my Date objects, setting them up at a different timezone than the one I have. A couple of examples:

- For the string `90=>Mon&Tue&Thu=>16:00` I get the Date object:  `2019-10-14T14:00:11.852Z`
- For the string `30=>Mon&Tue&Wed&Thu&Fri&Sat&Sun=>18:30` I get the Date object:  `2019-10-14T16:30:11.866Z`

I would like to know what's the explanation for such a behavior, and if I can do something to change it so the normal Javascript Date object points to the same hour than my momentjs object, or the .toISOString() output.

Thank you!

Comment: `toISOString()` is UTC time - Check difference between UTC and local time

Comment: @Weedoze thing is, that even modifying everything with just the JS Date API, trying to set a Date object to a given hour, will always return a date that points to two hours back in time, which makes no sense. new Date().setHours(18) will retrieve a Date object that points to 16:00, instead of 18:00. This makes no sense.

Comment: Your local time is UTC+2, and Date default to local timezone if the timezone is not explicitly given.

Comment: @mtkopone That's right, but why can't I explicitly change the hour of a given Date object, with .setHour(), or do it via momentjs? Do I have to sum the N in UTC-N always to get the desired hour?

Comment: `new Date().setHours(18)` doesn't return a Date object, it returns a time value for the adjusted time. Where is *currendDay* initialised? What is its value?

Comment: Can you please explain more about what the input string is intended to mean?  Given, `"90=>Mon&Tue&Thu=>16:00"` - Does that mean that the event occurs at `16:00` on Monday, Tuesday, and Thursday in time zones that are 90 minutes ahead of UTC?  (`UTC+01:30`)?  Or 90 minutes behind UTC? (`UTC-01:30`)?  Or does it mean something else?   I notice in your evaluation, you're using the local time zone to evaluate the day of week.  Is that intended? Or should you have been using the offset provided?

Comment: Also, there aren't actually any time zones in the world that have offsets that are 30 or 90 minutes before or ahead of UTC.  So is perhaps your first column not a time zone offset at all, but maybe the duration of the event?

Answer (score 0):

The posted code is incomplete and doesn't demonstrate the issue described.

I've reimplemented the code without moment.js as best I can and simplified it. It seems to work fine:

```js
function parseThing(s) {
  // Parse input string
  let b = s.split('=>');
  let offset = +b[0];
  let days = ['Sun','Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat'];
  let weekDays = b[1].split('&').map(day => days.indexOf(day));
  let [hr, min] = b[2].split(':');

  // Get a date for today
  let date = new Date();

  // If today included, return an adjusted date
  if (weekDays.includes(date.getDay())) {
    date.setHours(hr, min, 0, 0);

    if (offset) {
      date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes()+ Number(offset));
    }

    return date;
  }

  // If today isn't included, return null
  return null;
}

let s0 = '90=>Mon&Tue&Thu=>16:00';
let s1 = '0=>Mon&Tue&Wed&Thu&Fri&Sat&Sun=>18:30';

console.log(parseThing(s0).toString());
console.log(parseThing(s1).toString());
```

Where the local day is one of those in the string (Mon, Tue, Thu) it returns a Date equivalent to a local time of 17:30, which is 90 minutes offset from 16:00, which seems to be correct.

PS I've changed Sunday to 0 as I can't see any rationale for it to be 7. Also seconds and milliseconds are zeroed too.